# NestJS: Query parameters are incoming as arrays of strings

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have been struggling for a while with NestJS query parameters. Browser is sending request to this path:

`/v0/api/patients/674/insurancecard?isFront=true&size=small`

But on the server query data on the `req` object looks like this:

`{ isFront: [ 'true', 'true' ], size: [ 'small', 'small' ] }`

This is before it gets to transform^^

Expected `req.query` to look like this:

`{ isFront: 'true', size: 'small' }`

Controller:

```
export interface CustomRequest extends Request {
 credentials: AuthCredentials;
}
export class InsuranceCardDto {
  @IsString()
  size: 'small' | 'original';

  @IsBoolean()
  isFront: boolean;
}

@Controller('patients')
export class PatientsController {
  constructor(private readonly pateintsService: PatientsService) {}

  @Get(':id/insurancecard')
  @UserTypes('employee', 'admin', 'patient')
  @UseGuards(IsAuthenticatedGuard, UsersGuard)
  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true } }))
  async insuranceCard(
    @Param('id', ParseIntPipe) id: number,
    @Query() payload: InsuranceCardDto,
    @Req() { credentials: { userType, user } }: CustomRequest,
    @Res() res: Response,
  ) {...}
}
```

Current server config:

```
import { HttpException, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { urlencoded, json } from 'express';
import tlsconfig from './config/tlsconfig';
import { allowedOrigins } from './config';
import { AllExceptionFilter } from './middleware/exceptions.filter';
// import newLogger from './helpers/logger';

export async function bootstrap(): Promise<INestApplication> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { httpsOptions: tlsconfig, logger: ['error'] }); // IF you want to see all logs provide logger to nest. BetterPT Logger works too. Helps for debugging

  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.use(json({ limit: '20mb' }));
  app.use(urlencoded({ limit: '20mb', extended: true }));
  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionFilter());
  // app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true } }));

  app.enableCors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      if (origin && !allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) return callback(new HttpException('CORS error', 501), origin);
      return callback(null, origin);
    },
  });
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5511);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: @Bogdan Polovko, can you please put the code of the controller in the question too?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is a GET request. I used browser and postman to test it. I'm sure query parameters are send just once.

Comment: @TahmidAli I have updated the question with controller code

Comment: What is exactly expected here. Can you mention you problem statement more clearly?

Comment: Did you have a look at this
https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#query-type-names

Comment: @Sohan updated the question with the expected value

Comment: @Sohan did you look at i? :) That URL you shared is for GraphQL

Comment: Sorry my bad, but i think if you can access `@Query() payload: InsuranceCardDto`
that is `payload`, you should be able to the query params?

Comment: @Sohan the problem is that I don't want to write a custom class transformer for this, I should not be doing it for such a simple task. And because it is given to me as an array I'm getting class validation failures

Comment: Why are you using  `@UsePipes` ? Also can you paste output of `payload` ?

Comment: yes, I'm using UsePipes. Will provide output of payload soon

Comment: Sure, but i asked why are you using `ValidationPipe` here? paste output before and after removing that pipe

Comment: @BogdanPolovko sorry for bothering again, can you please add the  CustomRequest class too in the question?

Comment: @TahmidAli added CustomRequest

Comment: @Sohan this is current payload without the validation pipe:

Comment: `{ isFront: [ 'true', 'true' ], size: [ 'small', 'small' ] }`

Comment: It was exactly the same with the pipe, but it was at least throwing error because it was not what I was expecting

Comment: @BogdanPolovko, Could not use the interface `CustomRequest` as it contains `AuthCredentials` which is absent. 
I used `@Req` from `@nestjs/common` to test the code. Found that `req.query` is exactly the way you expected. Console output for r`eq.query` was `{ isFront: 'true', size: 'small' }`
In short, failed to reproduce the problem except the fact that I could not use the same `req` as mentioned in the question. :(

Comment: @TahmidAli thanks for trying. This is really odd, could be something wrong with my config

Comment: I think I'm going to end up using custom transform pipe and apply it to query

Comment: @TahmidAli I've added server setup too, do you see something odd?